# viewer.loadImageFromJSON with variable not working

Tags: javascript, function

I have the following javascript that works perfectly good (with jquery):

```
function(test) {            
        var neuroimages = viewer.loadImageFromJSON('../data/new/res_neg_subj_val_5.nii.json', 'neg_subj_val_5', 'hot and cold');
        return neuroimages;
    };
```

Now I want to use a variable (lets say `picture`) instead of the `'../data/new/res_neg_subj_val_5.nii.json', 'neg_subj_val_5', 'hot and cold'` and format the code accordingly:

```
function(test) {
                 picture = "'../data/new/res_neg_subj_val_5.nii.json', 'neg_subj_val_5', 'hot and cold'";   
                 neuroimages = viewer.loadImageFromJSON(picture);
                 return neuroimages;
                };
```

This does **not** work.

Neither does this:

```
function(test) {
                 pic1 = "'../data/new/res_neg_subj_val_5.nii.json', 'neg_subj_val_5', 'hot and cold'";  
                 pic2 = "'neg_subj_val_5'";
                 pic3 = "'hot and cold'";
                 neuroimages = viewer.loadImageFromJSON(pic1, pic2, pic3);
                 return neuroimages;
                };
```

What am I doing wrong there?
I tried google and several sites with no success. Not to mention that I'm quiet a beginner with Java and already near insanity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost right with the second example. Here you should only specify one piece of data for each variable (at least in your case, but there are ways to specify many pieces of data in a single variable such as arrays and objects). Also you only need to have one set of quotes surrounding each string (doesn't matter whether they are single or double quotes as long as they match). Also, precede your variables with the 'var' keyword unless you want them to be global.

```
function(test) {
  var pic1 = "../data/new/res_neg_subj_val_5.nii.json";  
  var pic2 = "neg_subj_val_5";
  var pic3 = "hot and cold";
  neuroimages = viewer.loadImageFromJSON(pic1, pic2, pic3);
  return neuroimages;
};
```

Making your first attempt work is a little more tricky as you are passing an array to a function that expects three distinct variables. You do it like this:

```
function(test) {
  var picture = ['../data/new/res_neg_subj_val_5.nii.json', 'neg_subj_val_5', 'hot and cold'];   
  neuroimages = viewer.loadImageFromJSON.apply(viewer, picture);
  return neuroimages;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to initialize an array here, but you need to have a string instead. Try changing this:

```
picture = "'../data/new/res_neg_subj_val_5.nii.json', 'neg_subj_val_5', 'hot and cold'";
```

to:

```
picture = "'../data/new/res_neg_subj_val_5.nii.json';
```

You are not specifying if viewer.loadImageFromJSON() can accept an array, instead of a string. If it can, you could do something like:

```
picture = ['../data/new/res_neg_subj_val_5.nii.json', 'neg_subj_val_5', 'hot and cold'];
```

Check here on how to initialize arrays in Javascript:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp

If you need more information on the issue, please attach the code for loadImageFromJSON(), so that we know how this function handles input and output

Comment: thanks for the external link, that helped a lot too (for the understanding, thou)!